# looking for corpus of dialogue recording in appointment between doctors and patients

Tags: computational-linguistics, resource-request, prosody, speech-recognition

I am looking for a public corpus of dialogue recording in short/medium appointment between doctors and patients, aims to study speech variation, the prosody of speech, measuring speech' rhythm, innovation and so on. I need relatively large audio recording sample, so I can train those on the specific neural network to precisely predict and classify the speech by different specific criteria.

I have searched from possible NLP labs around but couldn't find the corpus that meets my expected research. Is there any experienced linguistics experts could point me how to get possible corpus for NLP research?  Can anyone guide me how to acquire the corpus that I stated above? Thanks in advance

**secondary preferable corpus**

If getting above corpus is not feasible at this moment, I'd like to try other spoken recording corpus with the following specification:

1. corpus of monologue recording in reading newspaper/short stories, poem/reading basic sentence (English, Italian, or other European language can be taken into consideration)
2. corpus of the audio recording in conversation/dialogue between standard English/Italian (or other European languages) and its specific dialect counterpart.
3. or other language corpuses (spoken) that closely aligned the statement that I mentioned above.

Comment: I am sure you have heard about patient confidentiality.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about Linguistics or NLP. Questions about finding datasets may better fit at [opendata.se]. Namely, they have tags `medical` and `audio` which you may find useful. VTC/offtopic.

Comment: [Richard Frankel](https://medicine.iu.edu/faculty/4890/frankel-richard/), a sociolinguist, has done a very large amount of research on how doctors an patients interact.

Comment: Because of confidentiality, voice recordings could not be made public. Anonymized transcriptions would be allowed.

Comment: @user6726 Would it possible to acquire corpus that I stated above if I provide my research center' formal request and credential? Could you guide me the possible route I could give it try? Thanks

Comment: @jlawler How can I get possible research datasets (spoken audio recording samples) that I could use them for research purpose? Thank you

Comment: Don't  ask me; apply to Dr. Frankel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrary to the expectations of some commentators, doctor-patient corpora are available (under some conditions, needing to sign some licence and confidentially agreement) for research. The standard entry point for a search for such corpora is the [CLARIN Virtual Language Observatory](http://vlo.clarin.eu) and entering `doctor patient` in the search slit gives currently twelve results.

Here is a [bookmarked query](https://vlo.clarin.eu/?q=doctor%20patient)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this is definitely breathtaking for me to further explore.